# Store a reference an object into Mongoose and Mean JS

Tags: javascript, mongoose, meanjs, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I have an Article schema and a Tag schema. And I am trying to save an array of Tag object references to the Article.
**This is my Article schema:**

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
 ....
  title: {
    type: String,
    .....
  },
  content: {
   .....
  },
  .....
  tags: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tag'
  }]
});
```

**And the Tag schema:**

```
var TagSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
   .....
  },
  user: {
   ......
  },
  count: {
   .....
  }
});
```

In front end I have my controller.

```
'use strict';

// Articles controller
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', [
  '$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Articles', 'Tags', '$filter',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Articles, Tags, $filter) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    // Create new Article
    $scope.create = function(isValid) {
      $scope.error = null;

      if (!isValid) {
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'articleForm');

        return false;
      }

      var tagsArrays = this.tags.replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
      var tagsObjectArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < tagsArrays.length; i++) {
        // Create tag object
        var tag = new Tags({
          name: tagsArrays[i]
        });
        tagsObjectArray.push(tag);

        saveATag(tag);
        //article.tags.push(tag);
      }

      function saveATag(tempTag) {
        tempTag.$save(function(response) {
        }, function(errorResponse) {
          $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
      }

       // Create new Article object
      var article = new Articles.articles({
        title: this.title,
        content: this.content,
        tags: tagsObjectArray
      });

      // Redirect after save
      article.$save(function(response) {
        $location.path('articles/' + response._id);
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
      });
    };
```

**In back end I have my controller for Article:**

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var article = new Article(req.body);
  article.user = req.user;
  article.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(article);
    }
  });
};
```

When I try to save my array of tags in the Article i get the error:
**Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "tags"**
I have looked around and tried multiple ways, but still cannot get it to store in the database. All the routes for front and back end are set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Articles schema is expecting an array of tag ObjectIds and those Ids are generated automatically by Mongoose, but not until they reach the server.

From your Tag server controller:

```
var errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller')),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Tag = mongoose.model('Tag');

exports.createTag = function (req, res) {
    var tag = new Tag(req.body); // tag._id now exists

    tag.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)

            });
        } 
        else {
            res.json(tag);
        }
    });
};
```

So in your front-end controller you need to save all of the tags, then pull out just the _id fields from the save responses and put those into the array that you save with the article. Since the $save function is asynchronous, I'd suggest utilizing Angular's $q service, particularly the $q.all() function to ensure all the tags are saved before trying to save the article.

```
var promises = [];
var tag;
var tagIds = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tagsArrays.length; i++) {
    // Create tag object
    tag = new Tags({
        name: tagsArrays[i]
    });

    // $save() returns a promise, so you are creating an array of promises
    promises.push(tag.$save());
}

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function(tags) { 
        // When all the tag.$save() promises are resolved, this function will run
        for(i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
            // The response is an array of tag objects, extract the Ids from those objects
            tagIds.push(tags[i]._id);
        }

        var article = new Articles({
            title: this.title,
            content: this.content,
            tags: tagIds
        });

        // Save the article
        return article.$save();
    })
    .then(function(article) {
        // When the article save finishes, this function will run
        $location.path('articles/' + article._id);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your front end controller you're saving an array of objects where the only field is name. Meanwhile your mongoose model is expecting an array of objectIds, which are not objects, but the _id tags you get when you save document. Hence, Mongoose tries to convert the tags you gave it from an array of objects to an array of basically strings and throws an error. Since you're not saving the tags themselves and they're likely article specific don't give them their own Mongoose model just make tags an array of objects in Article of tags.

Comment: I am saving the tags in the database. The tags get saved successfully, i cans see them saved.

Comment: This is where I define a new tag and then save them: ` var tag = new Tags({
          name: tagsArrays[i] `
        });

Comment: Yes, you're saving the tags, but you're trying to save the tagObjectArray as tags in the article when tags in the Article model is an array of object Ids not an array of tag objects, which causes new Article(req.body) to throw an error in the server side controller

Comment: If your $save call for tags returns the created tag as a response, you could get the _id from response.data._id and push that to a tagsIdArray and save that as article.tags and the article would save correctly

Comment: The $save function does return the correct saved _id in the response. However, I can not save that value on response._id anywhere, becuase of asynchronous nature i think.

Comment: If I do something like this:   tempTag.$save(function(response) {         tagsObjectArray.push(response._id);  article.tags.push(response._id); ........   And sometimes later I do console.log(tagsObjectArray) it will be empty.